# Oracle SQL statement error - ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please help me with the following Oracle SQL Statement. I am getting an error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
ALTER TABLE loan_transaction_codes 
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (non_accrual_debit_code) 
   REFERENCES dbo.general_ledger_accounts (gl_account_no) 
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Database does not have an `ON UPDATE` clause in referential constraint syntax, it only has an `ON DELETE` (optional) clause; and the only options for `ON DELETE` are `CASCADE` and `SET NULL`, there is no `NO ACTION` option. Please refer to the Oracle documentation, which is very easy to find and read.